# php 4-5 dimensinal array advice overkill or not?

Tags: php, class, dynamic, crud

what i'm asking below issent a problem but a question regarding to what you! would do in my place.

i've started building my first dynamic php class, in the form off a table.

i've made it up like a factory class which takes 2 indputs on the `construct`:

```
$data = sql_query,
$columns = array(
                 array('type_checkbox' => 'name_of_id_to_look_for')
                 array('type_select' =>array(
                'select_class' => 'headline_name',
                'select_value1' => 'select_name1',
                'select_value2' => 'select_name2'))
                array('type_text' => 'headline_name')
);
```

the idea with this is changeing it on the fly with javascript diffrent states for viewing, editing, creating, so basicly CRUD

now is this overkill with a 4-5 layer deep array?
how would you do it?

Comment: In general, yes I am sensing this is a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

This is too small information for me, personally I don't know what kind of info will be presented in such multilevel array.

You must consider if it worth to make array of current item e.g. type_text.

I tried to optimize this but don't know if it helps. based on data that you give I manage to optimize like this

```
$columns = [
'type_checkbox' => 'name_of_id_to_look_for',
'type_text' => 'headline_name',
'type_select' => [
    'select_class' => 'headline_name',
    'select_value1' => 'select_name1',
    'select_value2' => 'select_name2'
]
```

];